# my alarm service run several times and not in actual time

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm

i have an alarm service that works with alarm manager. it's works correctly when you set alarm for later. but when you set it for past ( you want to alert you tomorrow) it gone crazy and alert several times instead of once and finally wont work tomorrow. 
some one plz help me on this.

i do like this: I have a alarm class. when i create it, so it make an pending intent that run a service with alarm manger. and the service  will open my activity.

is it the wrong way?

here is my alarm class:

```
public class MyAlarm  {

    private Context myContext;
    private NotificationManager mNM;
    private int NOTIFICATION = 10002; //Any unique number for this notification

    MyAlarm(Context myAct){



        myContext = myAct;
        showNotification();





    }
     // this constractor is for cancelling alarm

    MyAlarm(Context myAct, String str) {
        myContext = myAct;
        cancelPendigIntent();
    }

    private void cancelPendigIntent() {


        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(myContext, MyAlarmService.class);
        //G.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(myContext, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        //G.pendingIntent.cancel();
        //G.alarmManager.cancel(G.pendingIntent);

    }

    private void showNotification() {



         Intent myIntent = new Intent(myContext, MyAlarmService.class);
         G.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(myContext, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
         G.alarmManager = (AlarmManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         G.calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

         int to_day= G.calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
         int to_mounth= G.calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         int to_year= G.calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         G.calendar.set(to_year, to_mounth, to_day, Integer.parseInt(G.myPref.loadString("alert_time_houre")), Integer.parseInt(G.myPref.loadString("alert_time_mins")), 0);
         Log.i("LOG", "alert_time_houre="+G.myPref.loadString("alert_time_houre")+"  alert_time_mins="+G.myPref.loadString("alert_time_mins"));
         G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, G.calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, G.pendingIntent);




    }
```

Comment: How many times are you calling the showNotifications function ? because when ever you call it, the code inside this function is going to execute regardless of the alarm manager condition.

Comment: if (System.currentTimeMillis() > cal.getTimeInMillis()){
        cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis()+ 24*60*60*1000);// Okay, then tomorrow ...
    } -- use this along with your code..

Comment: @sayed.jalil it runs when ever in settings, save button had clicked. and i think this code cancel current and creates new one because of .cancel_current falg in:   G.pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(myContext, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Comment: @jigar pandya: i like to run my alarm automaticaly every day and dont want to customize it every day to alarm for tomorow! what would you think? and what the best way?

Comment: Then it should run properly. But you could use @jigar pandya's suggestion to check for the time condition

Comment: @sayed.jalil but if i do that may i fix tomarrow alarm but what about  every days alarm? they would'n they set with the wrong time? because my alarm mode is repeating mode

Comment: @Kenji :use this alarmMgr0 .setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);

Comment: @jigarPandya: ok i change it. i set the alarm for 9 am( now is 1 pm) and first problem is solved and i dont have any first notification. then change my date to tomorrow and time to 8:55 am to check alarm. but it wont works. should i wait till tomorrow to check what happens? thank u very much.

Comment: @JigarPandya noop friend it's wont working at all :(

Comment: Wait for tomorrow.It would work properly. Also refer - https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/tree/master/AndroidProjects/AlarmManagerExample

Comment: @Kenji:I implemented it for every 2 min and it is working fine :)

Comment: @JigarPandya can you manage it for daily alarm on a specific time? would you send me your code at: mahdi_t83@yahoo.com

Comment: I have given you link of that code in my above comment.please check out & kindly vote up my any answer if my comments have helped you in any way :)

Comment: @JigarPandya .my pending intent is kind of Service. is the problem from that?

Comment: my problem is still remaining and nothings changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find the answer.

my problem is not about alarm manager. 
i set the pendig intent to a service that opens a activity. the problem was while the service is run in background it opened my activity again and again and my app go crazy. maybe i should destroy the service after her job done once.

i change it from service to broadcastreceiver and it's works correctly.

thanks for guides :)